# Why undefine location in Flutter coonection with GraphQL?

Tags: flutter, graphql, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJV1u.png)
   Query(
   options: QueryOptions(documentNode: gql(
   r"""
   query getAllLookups{
   getAllLookups{
   nodes{
   _id
   name
   }
   totalCount    } }
   """ ),pollInterval: 1),
   builder: (QueryResult result, { VoidCallback refetch, FetchMore fetchMore }){
   return Center(child: result.hasException ? Text(result.exception.toString())
   :Text("comoplete"));

   ```
           return Center(child: Text("getting"));
         }

     ),**strong text**
   ```

Comment: Please include more info about what you want to achieve@darshan patel

Comment: yes i am getting error when i started connection with flutter app to GraphQL API and